# Increase iBeacon range

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ibeacon

So I am currently using one device as a transmitter with a specific major and minor value and its broadcasting with

```
self.peripheralData = [[[CSMBeaconRegion alloc] initAsTransmitter] peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:nil];
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.peripheralData];
```

And I am having a receiver that starts ranging and displays the major and minor value of the transmitter.

Everything works well. But when i start walking away from the device, and go beyond 10 meters, I lose connection.   When i walk back, i still do not have connection.  I can only restart the connection when I am less than 1m from the transmitter.

How can i increase the range of transmitter to its MAX?

Should I set some value to `peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower`?

Comment: When you speak of restarting a "connection", you are either mis-speaking, or talking about something other than the 1-way BLE advertising packets comprising the iBeacon system.

Answer (score 0):

The power of the iBeacon signal is based on BLE, you can't change it. The peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower is just use to calibrate ranging on the beacon.
Regarding your beacon not connecting when you come back in range, this is internal to the iBeacon system. It should work but sometimes there is a delay after you come in range of a beacon before your device detects it.

Comment: how will the range be if I ditch Beacons all together, and use the BLE. I assume its the same, but I am just curious if it might be different... ?

Comment: You will have more control but you will have to write a lot of code yourself to handle everything. I doubt you will be able to increase the range.

Comment: This is fundamentally mistaken; there are a variety of power levels possible for BLE devices.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong here.  When using an iPad or iPhone as a transmitter, you should be able to detect its iBeacon transmission beyond 10m, even if you can't reach the 50m nominal range.  Are you testing in an area with many obstructions?

And even if it does drop off at 10m, you should not have to return to 1m to detect it again (is that a typo?).  If you simply wait at 10m away, are you sure it won't detect it again?

While @Patrick-Tescher is correct that you cannot change the transmit power of an iOS device acting as an iBeacon, some hardware iBeacons like Radius Networks' [RadBeacon](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/radbeacon.html) do allow you to configure their transmitter power.  But you typically change the transmitter power with a proprietary mechanism that is specific to the beacon, and not with iOS APIs.

Also, while your iOS device may have a short range, dedicated hardware iBeacons often have a range that exceeds the 50m nominal range of Bluetooth LE.

Full disclosure:  I am an employee of Radius Networks.

Comment: Hi David. Any change you might be able to clear some doubts over phone?

Comment: I am still having issues with range. Do you have email/chat?

Comment: @Logoias my contact info is available on this Github project:  https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service